# Receiving error downloading with urllib via url

Tags: python, blob, urllib

Using the code below, this should have downloaded ~14,000 images. I know the call works for the cards because I ran this without the image download.

A blob file showed up in my downloads, but then was deleted. No files to be found.

Where is the potential error? When this is successful - where would they potentially download to?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\toril\OneDrive\Documents\Pokemon AI\image download.py", line 28, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://images.pokemontcg.io/sm75/1_hires.png", "sm75-1.jpg")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 241, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)

fields = ['card', 'c_image']
Cards = Card.all()

with open ('pokemontest3.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file: 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)

for card in Cards:
    card = (card.name, card.images.small)
    rows = card
    csvwriter.writerow(rows)    
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://images.pokemontcg.io/sm75/1_hires.png", "sm75-1.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Why all the CSV-code, if it's a problem with image-fetching?
2. Why downloading the same image is within a loop?
3. It looks like your traceback is truncated, and it's a simple "403 Forbidden" error:

```py
>> urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://images.pokemontcg.io/sm75/1_hires.png", "/tmp/sm75-1.jpg")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://images.pokemontcg.io/sm75/1_hires.png", "/tmp/sm75-1.jpg")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request
.py", line 241, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request
.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request
.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request
.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request
.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request
.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request
.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```